# Tips for continuing plot when the spearhead character is not the protagonist?

Tags: style, plot, conflict

In the story I am writing, the main character is not in control of the events of the story, I did this to create a strong sense of powerlessness, but I have found a problem. I am having difficulties introducing the plot points in ways that feel real, every way I have of introducing new plot points only seems to feel forced.

How can I introduce plot points to a non-spearhead character, without it feeling forced?

(In the unlikely event that it matters, the protagonist is a young underage soldier fighting for a guerrilla rebellion)

Answer (score 3):

Every protagonist wants something and is struggling to get it. Every plot point in a story consists of the protagonist's attempt to get the thing they desire and the things that frustrate that desire.

This does not require the protagonist to be in charge of events. Nor does it require that they achieve the thing they desire. For a great example of a protagonist who is not in change of events and does not achieve their desire, check out Evelyn Waugh's Sword of Honour trilogy (Men at Arms, Officers and Gentlemen, Unconditional Surrender).

But even though they are not in charge of events and are usually or even always frustrated by them, the protagonist still has a desire that they are struggling to achieve. History may be driven by forces beyond their control, but the story is driven by their desire and what they do to achieve it (whether successful or not).

So there is no reason that the protagonists lack of control over events should feel forced if you simply focus on what it is the protagonist desires and what they can do in an attempt to achieve it, even if that attempt is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 2):

Also read books like One Flew Over the Cuckoos Nest and Moby Dick, and the Great Gatsby, where the most proactive character isn't the viewpoint character. Analyze the ways these authors make it work, maybe even annotate the text in search of this, and then go back to your original manuscript and try to incorporate some of your findigs into it. Yes, this canbe tedious, but analyzing books can teach you much more than any other advice I could give you. Good luck!